# What is this 3D functionality on end of home screen of Android ICS called?

Tags: android, android-layout, 3d, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

What is this 3D plane functionality on left/right end of home screen of Android ICS 4.0.3 called ?

Please refer screenshots: [left 3D plane](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2B1DU.png) & [right 3D plane](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UMF6Z.png)

The screenshot is about the left & right end of the home screen with a widget on it. When at the left most part of the home screen, if we try further left...The screen tilts as shown in the screenshot.

Can a android application use this 3D functionality ? What is this functionality called and how can we use it ?

I have an idea which would involve moving the 3D plane of the application as shown in the screenshot and i am not a android programmer, So i am curious to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This specific effect (overscroll, as mentioned by Booger) was implemented specifically for the home screen and you can't access it. Some people have written their own implementations of view pager. [ViewPager3D](https://github.com/inovex/ViewPager3D) is one such implementation that uses a 3D perspective and implements an overscroll effect. I haven't tried ViewPager3D and you'd need some Android experience to integrate it into your application.

Comment: Thanks @Nick, does 'View Pager' come under Android 3D part ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by the "3D part". [The original ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) is part of Android, and that handles the side-to-side page swiping but has a flat 2D view. The ViewPager3D class actually extends that class to add things like the 3D effects. If you wanted to add your own 3D effects on top of that then you could either extend ViewPager3D yourself, or fork the project and edit your own version of it. It depends on what you want to do and your level of ability.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is called 'Overscroll'.

Comment: Overscroll is a more general term for allowing the user to scroll past the beginning/end of content. You're right that this could be called overscroll, but I thought we should be clear that it's just one particular implementation of it.

Comment: Are there other names?  If you know other ways to reference this, it probably would help the person who asked the question.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply, Can a android application use this 'Overscroll' functionality ?

Comment: What do you mean by use?  It will be there automatically for certain 'overscroll' conditions (like when the user is at the end of a listview, etc).  I know I have disabled it in my listview (so I am sure it can be enabled).  I am sure you have access to it, but I am not sure how (other than the API call I used in ListView that is a boolean for turning overscroll on and off).  Don't forget to mark answer as correct please.

Comment: @Booger, I don't think there's a specific name for this animation so 'Overscroll' is as good an answer as any. Just wanted to make that clarification.

Comment: Thanks Booger & Nick, By using it i meant... For example i am running a opera browser, can it have the same effect.But i got your point about listview.